# SwiftData crashes on trying to access struct property

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, swift-data

I've defined the following models in a Swift iOS application:

```swift
import Foundation
import SwiftData

@Model
class User: Identifiable {
    let id: UUID
    let name: String
    
    var location: NamedLocation?
    var friend: Bool = false
    
    init(id: UUID = UUID(), name: String) {
        self.id = id
        self.name = name
    }
}


struct NamedLocation: Codable {
    let name: String?
    let loc: Location
    
    init(name: String?, location: Location) {
        self.name = name
        self.loc = location
    }
}

enum Location: Codable {
    case address(String)
    case coordinates(Double, Double)
}
```

When I try to populate with test data to see how my user interface looks, it
works fine:

```
import SwiftUI
import SwiftData

struct HomeView: View {
    @Environment(\.modelContext) private var modelContext
    @Query private var items: [User]
    
    var body: some View {
        // other views omitted for brevity
        VStack(alignment: .leading, spacing: 16.0) {
            Text("your nearby friends")
            List {
                ForEach(items) { item in
                    HStack {
                        VStack {
                            Text(item.name)
                            
                            if let location = item.location {
                                Text(location.name ?? "unknown location")
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            .listStyle(.plain)
            .scrollContentBackground(.hidden)
            Spacer()
        }
    }
}

#Preview {
    let config = ModelConfiguration(isStoredInMemoryOnly: true, allowsSave: true)
    let container = try! ModelContainer(for: Schema([User.self]), configurations: config)
    
    for i in 1..<10 {
        var user = User(name: "Example User \(i)")
        container.mainContext.insert(user)
    }
    
    return HomeView().modelContainer(container)
}
```

But as soon as I add locations to the users, then my preview starts crashing
(and it also crashes when I test in the simulator).

```swift
for i in 1..<10 {
    var user = User(name: "Example User \(i)")
    container.mainContext.insert(user)

    // I looked at other SO answers, and they suggested the issue comes from
    // not saving the model before trying to modify its properties. No dice.
    try! container.mainContext.save()
    user.location = NamedLocation(name: "hurk", location: .coordinates(40.72, -75.49))
    try! container.mainContext.save()
}
```

The crash is `EXC_BREAKPOINT` on `User.location.getter`, and the crash logs
don't provide much detail.

```
Exception Type:  EXC_BREAKPOINT (SIGTRAP)
Exception Codes: 0x0000000000000001, 0x00000001c4352d5c
Termination Reason: SIGNAL 5 Trace/BPT trap: 5
Terminating Process: exc handler [82555]

Triggered by Thread:  0

Thread 0 Crashed::  Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread
0   SwiftData                              0x1c4352d5c 0x1c42d1000 + 531804
1   SwiftData                              0x1c435597c 0x1c42d1000 + 543100
2   SwiftData                              0x1c4316014 0x1c42d1000 + 282644
3   rdvz                                   0x100357830 User.location.getter + 332 (@__swiftmacro_4rdvz4UserC8location18_PersistedPropertyfMa_.swift:10)
4   HomeView.1.preview-thunk.dylib         0x101592f28 closure #1 in closure #1 in closure #1 in closure #1 in closure #1 in closure #2 in closure #1 in HomeView.__preview__body.getter + 476 (HomeView.swift:73)
5   SwiftUI                                0x1c49e38b8 0x1c4371000 + 6760632
6   HomeView.1.preview-thunk.dylib         0x101592b7c closure #1 in closure #1 in closure #1 in closure #1 in closure #2 in closure #1 in HomeView.__preview__body.getter + 144 (HomeView.swift:68)
7   SwiftUI                                0x1c52e0840 0x1c4371000 + 16185408
8   HomeView.1.preview-thunk.dylib         0x1015928cc closure #1 in closure #1 in closure #1 in closure #2 in closure #1 in HomeView.__preview__body.getter + 148 (HomeView.swift:67)
9   SwiftUI                                0x1c532f9a0 0x1c4371000 + 16509344
10  SwiftUI                                0x1c53379e4 0x1c4371000 + 16542180
11  SwiftUI                                0x1c4cfd750 0x1c4371000 + 10012496
12  SwiftUI                                0x1c5337a00 0x1c4371000 + 16542208
13  libswiftCore.dylib                     0x192adba04 withUnsafePointer<A, B>(to:_:) + 20
14  libswiftCore.dylib                     0x192c862ac withUnsafeMutablePointer<A, B>(to:_:) + 12
15  SwiftUI                                0x1c532f0f0 0x1c4371000 + 16507120
16  SwiftUI                                0x1c5330e24 0x1c4371000 + 16514596
17  SwiftUI                                0x1c5330838 0x1c4371000 + 16513080
18  SwiftUI                                0x1c533575c 0x1c4371000 + 16533340
19  SwiftUI                                0x1c52f7950 0x1c4371000 + 16279888
20  SwiftUI                                0x1c497bc10 0x1c4371000 + 6335504
21  SwiftUI                                0x1c5374abc 0x1c4371000 + 16792252
```

Why is this crash happening, and how do I fix it?

**Edit:** If I remove the member `loc` from `NamedLocation`, or I make it optional and `nil`, the preview stops crashing. Why? And how do I make it work?

**Edit 2:** I found out that the issue is related to how `Location` is persisted. I thought that its implementation of `Codable` was wrong, so I tried providing a manual one, but it does not work because the data passed to the decoding method does not match the data produced by the encoding method:

```swift
enum Location: Codable {
    case address(String)
    case coordinates(Double, Double)
    
    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
       case kind
       case address
       case latitude
       case longitude
   }

   init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
       let container = try! decoder.container(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self)
       // this assertion fails; SwiftData gives a container with keys "address" and "coordinates" for some reason
       let kind = try! container.decode(String.self, forKey: .kind)

       switch kind {
       case "address":
           let address = try! container.decode(String.self, forKey: .address)
           self = .address(address)
       case "coordinates":
           let latitude = try! container.decode(Double.self, forKey: .latitude)
           let longitude = try! container.decode(Double.self, forKey: .longitude)
           self = .coordinates(latitude, longitude)
       default:
           throw DecodingError.dataCorruptedError(forKey: .kind, in: container, debugDescription: "Invalid location type")
       }
   }

   func encode(to encoder: Encoder) throws {
       var container = encoder.container(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self)

       switch self {
       case .address(let address):
           try! container.encode("address", forKey: .kind)
           try! container.encode(address, forKey: .address)
       case .coordinates(let latitude, let longitude):
           try! container.encode("coordinates", forKey: .kind)
           try! container.encode(latitude, forKey: .latitude)
           try! container.encode(longitude, forKey: .longitude)
       }
   }
}
```

Comment: crash happens when you're accessing item.location in your SwiftUI view, it's likely that the issue is related to how SwiftData handles the persistence of the location property in your User model

Comment: @sai yes, how do I find out how it's handling the persistence so that I can fix it?

Comment: Review SwiftData Documentation: Start by thoroughly reviewing the SwiftData documentation. Look for any specific information or guidelines related to handling complex properties like NamedLocation.

Comment: Simplify your data model by removing the location property from the User model. See if the crash still occurs. If not, the issue is likely related to the location property or its persistence.

Comment: Try to reproduce the issue without using SwiftUI. This can help determine if the problem is specific to SwiftUI or if it's related to the data model or SwiftData integration.

Comment: Make sure you are using the latest version of SwiftData and any related dependencies. There might be a bug fix or improvement that addresses the issue you're encountering.

Comment: This is related to a apple bug mentioned here. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76645050/error-trying-to-use-swiftdata-property-based-on-an-enum-with-an-associated-value. (Location enum in your case)  Enums with associated values crashes due to multiple values error. Apparently it is fixed in xcode 15 rc.

Comment: @GinderSingh But I'm using the latest Xcode and the latest iOS to test this ;(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like SwiftData still can't handle enums with associated values properly. So you need to store the information in another way. One way is to add the associated values as optional properties to the main type.

Below is one such solution where I made them private and used the enum as a computed property

```
struct NamedLocation: Codable {
    let name: String?
    private let address: String?
    private let longitude: Double?
    private let latitude: Double?
    var location: Location? {
        if let address {
            return Location.address(address)
        } else if let longitude, let latitude {
            return Location.coordinates(longitude, latitude)
        } else {
            return nil
        }
    }

    init(name: String?, location: Location) {
        self.name = name
        switch location {
        case .address(let string):
            address = string
            latitude = nil
            longitude = nil
        case .coordinates(let long, let lat):
            longitude = long
            latitude = lat
            address = nil
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This is essentially how I ended up working around the issue. This is my first time trying to do native iOS development in like 10 years, I can't believe that the frameworks we're supposed to rely on are (still) so complex and buggy!